# How to `rm` files as awk action?

Tags: bash, awk

This one-liner:

```
sudo df /tmp \
  | grep '/tmp' \
  | expand - \
  | cut -d " " -f 12 \
  | sed 's/%//' \
  | awk '{ if ($1<50)
             $("sudo rm -rf /path/to/trash/files/*")
         }'
```

seems to have no effect, while this:

```
sudo df /tmp \
  | grep '/tmp' \
  | expand - \
  | cut -d " " -f 12 \
  | sed 's/%//' \
  | awk '{ if ($1<50)
             print $1
         }'
```

prints the percentage of disk used for tmp.

(The end goal is to flip the comparison around to `($1>50)`, but for testing I'm trying `<`.)

Comment: awk isn't shell. It's a completely separate tool with it's own syntax, semantics, and scope. So you can't use shell syntax to call shell commands inside an awk program any more than you could from a C program. You also don't need cut or sed when you're using awk but idk if any of them are needed or appropriate for whatever it is you're trying to do. Please [edit] your question to explain what it is you're trying to do given the output of `df /tmp` with an example of that output and the final result.

Comment: `$("sudo rm ...)` ought to generate an error similar to `awk: illegal field`.  Are you suppressing errors?

Comment: @WilliamPursell that won't generate an error, it's just a non-numeric string being dereferenced as a field number (0) - it's a no-op like awk '{$0}'`.

Comment: @EdMorton I believe that `$(sudo rm ...)` would be equivalent to `$(0)`, which would not generate an error, but the quotes are an issue.

Comment: @WilliamPursell No, theyre just quotes around a string literal. `"sudo rm -rf /path/to/trash/files/*"` could be `"foo"` or anything else non-numeric in the context of `$("...")`.

Comment: Interesting.  `awk version 20070501`, with `awk '{$("sudo")}'` gives: `awk: illegal field $(sudo), name "sudo "`

Comment: Sounds like that awk has a bug since per POSIX `Each expression shall have either a string value, a numeric value, or both. Except as stated for specific contexts, the value of an expression shall be implicitly converted to the type needed for the context in which it is used. A string value shall be converted to a numeric value...` so a string in the context of a field number should be converted to a number.

Comment: That is right. `awk 'BEGIN{$("date")}'` returns no error and prints nothing while using `gnu-awk` but when I use `BSD-awk` on OSX then it prints `illegal field $(date), name "date "`

Comment: The awk from `mawk-1.3.3-17+b3` also gives no error, but I think BSD is not incorrect here.  The `()` changes the context, so that the value does not need to be converted to numeric.

Comment: AFAIK `anything` in the context of `$anything` needs to be converted to numeric whether that `anything` is within `()` or not since `$` only operates on numbers. Having said that, it's not a bad thing to get an error message for this particular case (gawk gives a warning when run with `--lint`) but you also get it for an uninitialized variable (try `echo 3 | awk '{print $var}'`) and IMHO that IS a bug since the type of `var` is `numeric-string` with value `0-or-null` depending on context and we're using it in a clearly numeric context so it should be treated the same as `var=0; print $var`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't really need so many commands in pipeline with `awk`.

You can just use:

```
df /tmp | awk 'NR>1 && $5+0 > 50 {system ("date")}'
```

Here change `date` command to something else that you need to run there.